# Measuring distance covered in netlogo

Tags: netlogo, agent

Does anyone have code to report how much a turtle travels during an experiment?
or to plot patches travelled?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [NetLogo: Recording distance a turtle has traveled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22488244/netlogo-recording-distance-a-turtle-has-traveled)

Comment: I'd suggest opening a new question on the "plot patches travelled" part, but be much more complete and specific about what you mean by that phrase, I could imagine it meaning several different things.